# How to access files in a specified existing folder in src directory?

Tags: java, io, filepath

I have a folder called "all_users" in my java project under the src directory.How can I access the files(if there are any) in the all_users folder. I eventually want to loop through all the existing files in the "all_users" folder, comparing whether the file name is equal to a string i specify in the code.

Firstly, I tried `File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.pathSeparator + "all_users");` as the file object then later tried `File dir = new File(TEST_PATH);` Both returned false when i checked if it existed so i didn't set up the path correctly?

```
public class ValUtility {
    static final String TEST_PATH = "./all_users/";



    public static boolean validUsername(String user) {


        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.pathSeparator + "all_users");

        File dir = new File(TEST_PATH);
        File[] directoryListing = f.listFiles();
        System.out.println(f.exists());
        System.out.println(directoryListing);
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                // Do something with child
                // think child is filename?
                if (user.equals(child.getName())){
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you printed out `dir.getCanonicalPath()` to see if it points where you think it does?

Comment: Why do you expect "user.home" to point inside your `src` directory?

Comment: As you said if 'all_user' folder under 'src' folder then `static final String TEST_PATH = "./src/all_users";`change need to be done.user `dir.getCanonicalPath()` to clearly identify your location.

Comment: Inside of the `src` directory? I don't know your project config, but in general these files are copied to the `target/bin` directory, means try to read from classpath instead...

Answer (score 0):

Please run...

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

The above will inform you where you need to add a folder labeled 'all_users'.  It is very unlikely that your 'user.home' property is set to your project's source file (src) folder.